# Marshall a Map into BSON by always retaining the same order

Tags: go, mongodb-indexes

I have a map, which I create from a slice of strings. I then want to marshal this into bson format, to insert into mongodb as an index. However, because of how maps are created in Golang, I get a different ordering of the index each time (sometimes its abc, othertimes its bac, cba...).

How can I ensure that the marshalled index created is always in the same order?

```
fields := ["a", "b", "c"] 

compoundIndex := make(map[string]int)
for _, field := range fields {
    compoundIndex[field] = 1
}
data, err := bson.Marshal(compoundIndex)
fmt.Println(string(data)) // This output is always in a different order than the desired abc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an ordered representation of a document, [bson.D](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#D):

```
var compoundIndex bson.D
for _, field := range fields {
    compoundIndex = append(compoundIndex, bson.E{Key: field, Value: 1})
}
data, err := bson.Marshal(compoundIndex)
fmt.Println(string(data)) // The elements are always printed in the same order.
```

[Run an example on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qq1-Z_Z4WEE).

Comment: is there a typo? should it be append(compoundIndex, bson.D instead of append(compoundIndex, bson.E (change E to D)? Thanks fo answering my question :)

Comment: @testing495 it is not a typo. `bson.D` is a `[]E`, an ordered list of `E`ntries.

Comment: Interesting, I get "E not declared by package bsoncompilerUndeclaredImportedName
" when I use that

Comment: @testing495  The answer assumes that `bson` is  a recent version of the package [go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.5.2/bson).  Which package are you using for bson?

Comment: ah Im using go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver v1.4.6

Comment: Version 1.4.6 has type [E](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.4.6/bson#E).